# Create reusable uiview in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have 1 `UIView` which will be added to my `UITableViewCell` like this. Although it will be called only 1 time, I feel like it is expensive to do. (At first time, it lag. After scroll up and down, it is fast since it is already created) How can I create that view so that it can be reused again and again for other cell as well (no need to init again)?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    // Initialization code
    self.vwHeaderWithUserAction = [HeaderWithUserActionInListing loadFromNib];
    self.vwHeaderWithUserAction.delegate = self;
    self.vwHeaderWithUserAction.viewTypeInUserAction = ViewTypeInUserActionInListing;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.vwHeaderWithUserAction];
}
```

Comment: Could you try to set reuse indentifier for UITableViewCell?

Comment: if you reuse an instance of the `UITableViewCell`, its subviews will be reused as well.

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method check whether that view is existing if not create new one otherwise use existing one.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewLocal cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (!myview)
     {
         // Initialize myView
      }
  // Do Necessary things 
   [cell.contentView addSubview:myview];
}
```